# characterising the square 2x2 matrices on types of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If A is a 2 X 2 matrix with complex entries, then A is similar over $C$ to a matrix of one of the two types :-

1. \begin{bmatrix}
      a & 0 \\
      0 & b 
    \end{bmatrix}
2. \begin{bmatrix}
      a & 0 \\
      1 & a 
    \end{bmatrix}
   We know we get 2 eigenvalues since the matrix is over complex numbers.
   If the Eigenvalues are distinct, or if they are equal with geometric multiplicity 2 then it's similar to type 1. If they are equal but the geometric multiplicity is 1 then we get one eigenvector, how do I find out the other basis element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v\neq(0,0)$ is such that $A.v=av$, solve the equation $A.w=aw+v$. That will give you the other vector that you are looking for.

Comment: I know, I got that. But how are we sure to get such a vector?

Comment: Every square matrix is similar to a lower triangular matrix. In particular, if $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix whose only eigenvalue is $a$, then $A$ is similar to a matrix of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\\lambda&a\end{smallmatrix}\right),$with $\lambda\neq0$. This means that there are vectors $v$ and $w$ such that $A.v=av$ and that $A.w=aw+\lambda v$. It is now not hard to define a vector $w^\star$ such that $A.w^\star=aw^\star+v$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Deeply appreciate it.